# Testing components using next-translate and i18n

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, internationalization, react-testing-library

In our Next.js app we use **vinissimus/next-translate** package for translations.
We set it up accordingly:

**next.config.js**:

```
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate')
module.exports = nextTranslate()
```

**i18n.js config file**:

```
{
  "locales": ["en"],
  "defaultLocale": "en",
  "pages": {
    "*": ["en"],
    "/": ["en"],
  }
}
```

Using it inside the component with **useTranslation** hook:

```
const App = () => {
  const { t, lang } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <Homepage>
          <span>{t(`${lang}:homepage.title.header`)}</span>
    </Homepage>
```

My question is how can I test it with jest with react-testing-library?

When I'm rendering my component in tests the translations do not work, only the key is returned. Also, I'd like to test it by **getByText / findByText** and passing:

```
{t(`${lang}:homepage.header`)}
```

How can I setup some kind of a wrapper or config for tests if I'm not using any **i18nProvider** in app but only this **i18n.js** config?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example wrapper:

```
// tests/wrapper.js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import I18nProvider from 'next-translate/I18nProvider'

import commonEN from '../locales/en/common.json'

const Providers = ({ children }) => (
  <I18nProvider
    lang={'en'}
    namespaces={{
      common: commonEN
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </I18nProvider>
)

const customRender = (ui, options = {}) => render(ui, { wrapper: Providers, ...options })

export * from '@testing-library/react'

export { customRender as render }
```

A test would look like

```
// App.spec.js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from './tests/wrapper'
import App from './App'

jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter() {
    return {
      asPath: '/'
    }
  }
}))

describe('App', () => {
  it('should render the app', async () => {
    const res = render(<App />)
  })
})
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work for me.. it seems that something is amiss since I'm using Trans inside my form and I got this error:

[next-translate] "register:countries.AE" is missing in current namespace configuration. Try adding "countries.AE" to the namespace "register"

Seems it still needs a little tweaking.. Especially that I use several namespaces